# Data validation in a Modular API

Tags: java, c#, rest, api, architecture

Below I present the project tree (simplified version)

Solution is divided into three Assembly (Entities(classes for tables in the database), Modules and API)

```
MyProject.Entities
MyProject.Modules
- AModule
    - Logic
    - Models
    - Repositories
    - Helpers
    - Validators
- BModule
    - Logic
    - Models
    - Repositories
    - Helpers
    - Validators
MyProject.RestAPI
- Controllers
- Security
- Validators
```

**I need to add data validation**

Each module has its own catalog of Validators and the API also has its own.

Is this correct?

`RestAPI -> Validators` will contain validators, attributes for validation common to **all modules**

`Modules -> AModule -> Validators` will contain validators, validation attributes associated only with this module

**Do I approach the modular REST API correctly?**